# Japanese Woodblock Effect using CoreImage or GPUImage

Tags: ios, gpuimage, core-image

I am trying to create an app that simulates a woodblock print effect similar to the app [Moku Hanga](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/moku-hanga/id506703833?mt=8). I have tried many combinations of the built in CoreImage and GPUImage filters but have not had success. I don't have any experience with OpenGL and GLSL, but I understand that it is possible to write custom CoreImage Kernels in iOS8 and custom fragment shaders in GPUImage. I am learning more about the iOS graphics pipeline and OpenGL ES shaders, but I'll still have to understand more about image manipulation so I can mimic this effect.

Does anyone have recommendations on how I could simulate the Moku Hanga effect using one of these frameworks or approaches (filter composition or custom shader)?